# Java : Encoding windows and linux

Tags: java, windows, unix, jdbc, encoding

I have a java class that retrieves a variable from the base and compares it with a value that is 'Transférée'.

```
isOK = "Transférée".equals(demande.getEtat());
```

When I debug the code in windows that work fine and give me `true`.

but when I generate the jar to run it in unix that give me  `false`.

I change the encoding of the project to **ISO-8859-**1 and **UTF-8** but the I have the same problem.

When I displayed the value of `demande.getEtat()` in the logs that give me Transf¿r¿e.

I used simple request JDBC for the database connection.

Comment: Where did the value of `demande.getEtat()` come from? Is the value correct there?

Comment: The string literal `"Transférée"` uses non-ASCII characters, so the encoding of the Java source file is important. If on Windows, did you both edit *and* compile using Windows character set, e.g. Windows-1252? Once compiled, the `.class` files can be moved without encoding issues, but moving the source file between Windows and Linux may cause issues if you don't explicitly defined the character set.

Answer (score 0):

It was an problem of data in the database